# Add phone number to wordpress registration

Tags: wordpress, forms, authentication, registration

Does anyone know how to add a phone number to the registration form  of wordpress when someone registers as a user to a wordpress website?

Comment: Which registration plugin do you have used?

Comment: For this you will have to take help of a plugin or either create custom and store it into user meta.

Comment: I haven't tried any of them yet. All of the ones I looked at didn't seem to have a field for a phone number.

Comment: Dp EN - What do you mean by "either create custom" a custom what?

Comment: You can use https://wpeverest.com/wordpress-plugins/user-registration/ this plugin gives an option to add a number in the registration form, which is also visible in the all user tab in WordPress (under the extra info tab). worked for me.